# How to open just one instance of my application

Tags: java, android

I found around this code

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

and it's working but when I open another instance of my application the old one is deleted and the new one is created, I would like the old one to stay alive and the new one will just turn to the old one.

Comment: one instance => singleInstance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you exit the activity via the back button (and through some other means, but not by pressing the Home button), it is destroyed and will be recreated the next time you access it. You can however save instance data in the savedInstanceState that you will get handed in the onCreate method.

Comment: But I change the onDestroy() method to public void onDestroy() {
  super.onPause();  
 }

Comment: onDestroy() is only a hook-method that gets called by the framework to let you handle the destruction (e.g. to save your state information). Overriding will not save your activity from being destroyed.

Comment: Then how many game applications I got when I click the home button and then click again on the app it's load the game from where it stopped.

Comment: I'm such an idiot, I putted the launchMode line in the application tag instead of the activity tag. thanks for your help mate!

Answer (score 0):

If the activity destroyed by the system, a new instance of your activity will be created when you open application. If it was only paused/stopped, you will get back the "old" activity.

Comment: It's not destroyed cause I did: public void onDestroy() {
  super.onPause();  
 }

Comment: It doesn't matter. The system can destroy it anytime, if there aren't enough resources for example.

Comment: Then how many game applications I got when I click the home button and then click again on the app it's load the game from where it stopped.

Comment: Because the system doesn't need more resources. It will be alive for a while.

Comment: I still I don't understand how can I do that in my app?and I don't think that my app is destroyed since when I go to the app info I got the option to force stop which means the app is running and it also on the running list, which means it's on the pause state and it still open a new instance of my app and kill the old one.

Comment: Did you try "singleTop"? Maybe this is for you.

Answer (score 0):

try to Use `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in your manifest for activity and see if this helps.

Comment: It gives me the same result.